# accordion table rows and unchanged table row after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do accordion table row.
I want to expand/collapse table row on the button click.
(plus (+) button to expand the row and minus (-) button to collapse the row)

It should work the same way from the header.
By default, the page initially open with all rows collapsed and 
keep the current condition of table unchanged after refreshing the page.

This is the image of what I actually want to do:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMZbP.png)

Here is the code

css:

```
 table, tr, td, th
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

html:

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Large<a class="LargeToggleAll" href="#">+</a></th>
      <th>Medium<a class="MediumToggleAll" href="#">+</a></th>
      <th>Small</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

 <tr id="test1" class="pa-dt-master-account-level" 
   data-account-level="master">
    <td>
            <a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleLarge" href="#">+</a>
            Test1
        </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tbody data-owner="test1">
  <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
            <tr id="test1-1" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" 
      data-owner="test1" data-account-level="group">
        <td></td>
                <td><a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test1-1</td>   
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-owner="test1">
    <tr id="test1-1-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test1-1"  
    data-account-level="account">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                <td>Test1-1-1</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test1">
    <tr id="test1-1-2" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test1-1"  
      data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
            <td>Test1-1-2</td>
      </tr>  
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test1">
  <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
            <tr id="test1-2" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" 
      data-owner="test1" data-account-level="group">
        <td></td>
                <td><a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test1-2</td>   
        <td></td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test1">
    <tr id="test1-2-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test1-2"  
       data-account-level="account">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                <td>Test1-2-1</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>


<tr id="test2" class="pa-dt-master-account-level" 
   data-account-level="master">
    <td>
            <a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleLarge" href="#">+</a>
            Test2
        </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tbody data-owner="test2">
  <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
            <tr id="test2-1" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" 
      data-owner="test2" data-account-level="group">
        <td></td>
                <td><a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test2-1</td>   
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-owner="test2">
    <tr id="test2-1-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test2-1"  
    data-account-level="account">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                <td>Test2-1-1</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test2">
    <tr id="test2-1-2" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test2-1"  
      data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
            <td>Test2-1-2</td>
      </tr>  
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test2">
  <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
            <tr id="test2-2" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" 
      data-owner="test2" data-account-level="group">
        <td></td>
                <td><a class="pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test2-2</td>   
        <td></td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody data-owner="test2">
    <tr id="test2-2-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-owner="test2-2"  
       data-account-level="account">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                <td>Test2-2-1</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>      

</table>
```

javascript:

```
   $(function () {
    // Hide all group and account level
    $('.pa-dt-group-account-level').hide();
    $('.pa-dt-account-level').hide();

    // Define our button for toggling
    var button = $( "a.pa-dt-toggle" );

    button.click(function() {
        // get the parent ID
        var parentId = $(this).parents('tr').attr("id");
        // get the parent account level
        var accountType = $(this).parents('tr').attr("data-account-level");

        console.log(parentId);
        console.log(accountType);

        $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');

        if ($(this).hasClass("pa-dt-toggle-active")) {
            $(this).removeClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
            $('[data-owner="' + parentId +'"]').hide();

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
            $('[data-owner="' + parentId +'"]').show();
        }
    });
    button.click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

                $('.LargeToggleAll').click(function () {

                    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');

                    $(".toggleLarge").each(function(){

                            if ($(this).hasClass("pa-dt-toggle-active")) {

                                $(this).removeClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
                                $('[data-account-level="group"]').hide();
                                $('[data-account-level="account"]').hide();
                                  $(this).text("+");
                                $(".MediumToggleAll").text("+");

                            } else {

                                $(this).addClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
                                $('[data-account-level="group"]').show();
                                $(this).text("-");
                                }
                    })
              });

              $('.MediumToggleAll').click(function () {

                    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');

                  $(".toggleMedium").each(function(){

                            if ($(this).hasClass("pa-dt-toggle-active")) {

                                $(this).removeClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
                                $('[data-account-level="account"]').hide();
                                $(".toggleMedium").text("+");

                            } else {
                                $(this).addClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
                                $('.MediumToggleAll').addClass('pa-dt-toggle-active');
                                $('[data-account-level="group"]').show();
                                $('[data-account-level="account"]').show();
                                $(".toggleLarge").text("-");
                                $(".toggleMedium").text("-");
                    $(".LargeToggleAll").text("-");
                                }
                    })
             });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/2494/ and however it does not seem to work as expected.
I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: don't use tables. try using positioning, padding, margins...

Comment: Agree with @TricksfortheWeb

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `div` would be better.

Here is something I come up with, the good part is that you can go with any number of level by defining `data-level`.

```js
$(function() {

  function getToogleFlag(sourceElement) {

    return (sourceElement.attr('data-collapse') === '1');
  }

  function setToggleButtonStatus(sourceElement, flag) {

    // Flag: 1-> Collapsed, 2-> Expanded

    if (flag === true) {

      // Set to collapsed
      sourceElement.attr('data-collapse', '1').text('+');
    } else {

      sourceElement.removeAttr('data-collapse').text('-');
    }
  }

  function setToggleButtonStatusToggle(sourceElement) {

    var curFlagValue = sourceElement.attr('data-collapse');

    if (curFlagValue === '1') {

      // Toggle to expanded
      setToggleButtonStatus(sourceElement, false)
    } else {

      // Toggle to expanded
      setToggleButtonStatus(sourceElement, true)
    }

  }

  function getToogleButton(source) {
    return $('.toggleButton', source);
  }


  // Parse level by reading 'data-level' attribute
  function getLevel(el) {

    var dataLevel = el.attr('data-level');
    //console.log( 'Data lavel to be parsed: ' + dataLevel);

    if (dataLevel) {

      // Parse available level
      return parseInt(el.attr('data-level'));

    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  // Handles show/hide of level item
  function showOneLevelDeepItem(levelElement, show) {

    function startCheck(parentElement) {

      var curNextItem = parentElement.next();

      // Ensuure next item received
      if (curNextItem.length === 0) return;

      // Get next element level
      var curNextItemLevel = getLevel(curNextItem);

      if (curNextItemLevel === level || curNextItemLevel < level) {

        // No more check required
        // Reached to next same level item
        // or higher level.
        return;
      }
      /*
      else if ( curNextItemLevel > validLevel && !show){

          // Hide all nested deep level elements
          curNextItem.hide();

          // continue with next check
          startCheck( curNextItem, false );
      }*/
      else if (curNextItemLevel > validLevel) {

        // continue with next check
        startCheck(curNextItem);

      } else if (curNextItemLevel === validLevel) {

        // Set found flag to true
        isFound = true;

        // Found one level deep item
        show ? curNextItem.show() : curNextItem.hide();

        // continue with next check
        startCheck(curNextItem);
      }

    }

    // Find toggle button within level element
    var toggleButton = $('.toggleButton', levelElement),

      // Get level of current element
      level = getLevel(levelElement),

      // Valid item level will be one level deeper
      validLevel = (level + 1),

      // Flag if child item(s) found
      isFound = false;

    // Find next level item that needs to be show/hidden
    startCheck(levelElement);

    if (isFound) {
      setToggleButtonStatus(getToogleButton(levelElement), !show);
    }

  }

  function showLevelItem(source) {
    showOneLevelDeepItem(source, true);
  }

  function hideLevelItem(source) {

    function check(startElement) {

      var nextElement = startElement.next(),
        nextElementLevel = getLevel(nextElement);

      if (nextElement.length === 0) {

        // No more items
        return;
      } else if (nextElementLevel === sourceLevel) {

        // Encountered same level item
        return;
      } else if (nextElementLevel < sourceLevel) {

        // Reached one level up
        return;
      } else if (nextElementLevel >= oneDeepLevel) {
        coll.push(startElement);
        //showOneLevelDeepItem( startElement, false );
        check(nextElement)
      }
    }


    var
      // Source level
      sourceLevel = getLevel(source),

      // One deep level
      oneDeepLevel = (sourceLevel + 1),

      // collection of items
      coll = [];

    check(source);

    for (var i = coll.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      showOneLevelDeepItem(coll[i], false);
    }
  }

  function expandItem(expandItemElement, show) {



    function checkNext(curElement) {

      // Get the next element
      var el = curElement.next();
      //console.log( el );

      // On no more next element, exit
      if (el.length === 0) return;

      // Get next element level
      var nextLevel = getLevel(el);

      if (nextLevel === levelToMatch) {

        // This is direct child element
        // we need to toggle this
        showHideElement(expandItemElement, show);
        checkNext(el);
      } else if (nextLevel > levelToMatch && !show) {

        // For hiding, all sub level elements
        // needs to be hidden
        showHideElement(el, false);
        checkNext(el);
      } else if (nextLevel > levelToMatch) {
        // This is higher level then we need to match
        // just ignore and continue with next
        checkNext(el);
      } else if (nextLevel === level) {
        // Matched with same level element
        // Need to stop
      } else {
        // level not found for this element
        // continue with next
        checkNext(el);
      }
    }

    var level = getLevel(expandItemElement),
      levelToMatch = level + 1;

    checkNext(expandItemElement);

  }

  function expandAllClick() {

    var el = $(this),
      level = parseInt(el.attr('data-all-level')),
      flagShow = getToogleFlag(el);

    var foundElements = $('[data-level=' + level + ']');

    foundElements.each(function() {

      // Current found element
      var curElement = $(this);

      if (flagShow) {
        showLevelItem(curElement);
      } else {
        showOneLevelDeepItem(curElement, false);
      }

    });

    // Toggle button update
    setToggleButtonStatusToggle(el);
  }

  function toggle() {

    // Get toggle button
    var toggleButtonClicked = $(this);

    // Get the container element on which button is clicked
    var container = toggleButtonClicked.closest('tbody'),
      flagShow = getToogleFlag(toggleButtonClicked);

    //console.log('Flag: ' + flagShow);

    if (flagShow) {
      showLevelItem(container);
    } else {
      hideLevelItem(container)
    }

    //showOneLevelDeepItem( container, flagShow );        

    //expandItem(  container, flagShow  );
    //setToggleButtonStatusToggle( toggleButtonClicked );

  }

  $('.toggleButton').click(toggle);

  // Initially collapse all
  $('[data-level=2],[data-level=3]').hide();

  // Expand all
  $('[data-all-level]').click(expandAllClick);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: gray;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #B1B1B1;
}

table th {
  background-color: #DFEFF0;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.toggleButton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  background-color: burlywood;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Large<a data-all-level="1" data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  LargeToggleAll" href="#">+</a></th>
      <th>Medium<a data-all-level="2" data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  MediumToggleAll" href="#">+</a></th>
      <th>Small</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody data-level="1" class="level1">
    <tr id="test1" class="pa-dt-master-account-level" data-account-level="master">
      <td>
        <a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton toggleButton pa-dt-toggle toggleLarge" href="#">+</a> Test1
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>



    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="2" class="level2">
    <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
    <tr id="test1-1" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" data-account-level="group">
      <td></td>
      <td><a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  toggleButton toggleButton pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test1-1</td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="3">
    <tr id="test1-1-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test1-1-1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="3">
    <tr id="test1-1-2" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test1-1-2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="2" class="level2">
    <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
    <tr id="test1-2" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" data-account-level="group">
      <td></td>
      <td><a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  toggleButton pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test1-2</td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="3" class="level3">
    <tr id="test1-2-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test1-2-1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>





  <tbody data-level="1">
    <tr id="test2" class="pa-dt-master-account-level" data-account-level="master">
      <td>
        <a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  pa-dt-toggle toggleLarge" href="#">+</a> Test2
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tbody data-level="2">
    <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
    <tr id="test2-1" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" data-account-level="group">
      <td></td>
      <td><a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test2-1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody data-level="3">
    <tr id="test2-1-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test2-1-1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-level="3">
    <tr id="test2-1-2" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test2-1-2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-level="2">
    <!-- GROUP ACCOUNT -->
    <tr id="test2-2" class="pa-dt-group-account-level" data-account-level="group">
      <td></td>
      <td><a data-collapse="1" class="toggleButton  pa-dt-toggle toggleMedium" href="#">+</a>Test2-2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-level="3">
    <tr id="test2-2-1" class="pa-dt-account-level" data-account-level="account">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Test2-2-1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. However the result is a little different from what I actually want. The result should be as below. 
The small column should be expanded on the Header (Medium+) Click 
only when there is data in medium column.
The Header (Large+) button should expand only medium column 
and The Header (Large-) button should collapse both medium and small column.And also please give an advice how to keep/save the current condition of table row  unchanged after refreshing the page.
Appreciate for your help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look through code and modify to meet this requirement.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yes, table being drawn from server side code.